# Can a digital signature be used in place of actual signature on legal documents

Tags: digital-signature

This isn't exactly on topic for stackoverflow but I have a feeling that someone has come across this issue before and while I was trying to research into it a little, I could not find an answer.

I have an online store where people can purchase Items that are considered to be "tax exempt". The online store is new and we currently just have them fill out a tax exempt form when they come in the store if we don't already have them in our records. I am trying to figure out how to handle tax exemptions for the online store.

A requirement is that we must have the form that the customer filled out at the store with their signature on the form. In order for a new customer online, who has not previously filled out a form, to immediately receive the tax exemption for their purchase I was wondering if it is legal for them to fill out a PDF and "digitally sign" the form, if this is considered valid or does their signature have to be hand-written?

Comment: *Can a digital signature be used in place of actual signature on legal documents* - **A)** For which legislation? **B)** Which kinds of digital signatures? ... In some countries qualified electronic signatures even have a higher value than normal, written signatures. You should talk to the agency to which those tax exemption forms are to be forwarded. And a lawyer.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what legislation could you possibly elaborate, and I am wondering if just a simple Times New Roman font could be used as their "Signature" Or if it gets a lot more complicated than that (which, I am a little worried that it is much more complicated).

Comment: do you mean like Bill, joint resolutions, concurrent resolutions and simple resolutions?

Comment: *I'm not exactly sure what legislation could you possibly elaborate* - According to which country's law? German? Swiss? French? Italian? ... *I am wondering if just a simple Times New Roman font could be used as their "Signature"* - I doubt it but you had better ask the agency in question.

Comment: Sorry, the US legislation. And yea, it is starting to sound like I should consult the agency or lawyer like you mentioned earlier to be positive about what is and isn't allowed.

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea about the US American practices in regard to electronic signatures and public agencies.

Comment: That's ok thanks for your responses anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not confuse a scanned or digitalized signature with a "digital signature" that has to be validated by a recognized Certification authority to be legally binding.

In order to add a digital signature you need a "digital certificate" that is stored in your computer.

You can associate a scanned signature to the "digital signature" but the truly important one is the part associated to the digital certificate.

Anyone can scan any document signed by you and use it elsewhere so that has no value...

Comment: Oh, so the "digital signature" is would only be valid after going through the other authentication and verification steps? In other words, They can't type their name in the box with regular font and submit it and it be valid without the certificate?

Comment: Yes. The digital certificate makes sure that the procedure has been carried out by the person is supposed to be. Although a little off-topic you may have a look at how to add a digital signature to a Word document because that may clarify you a little bit the procedure.

Answer (score 2):

For our business we use digital signatures then print them out on the documents we need to hand in to the government. We where using [Jsignature](http://willowsystems.github.io/jSignature/#/about/) to get the online signatures witout having them mail or photocopy their signature. We then use a php PDF generator to automaticly put their signature onto the PDF that we can print out. If you want to see a working example go through this [Signup](http://www.payrollexpress.com/sign_up/) process. To see how we implemented it on our clients site.

Comment: Do you know if it is the "same" as using something like Jsignature if the customer were to simply just type their name in the signature box with ordinary font (Times New Roman, for example)?

Comment: I'm not a hundred percent sure. As far as our clients are concerned they need the signature to do invoices with the bank. So i would talk to your bank and ask what they need from you. If they need a signature, give them Jsig. If they need just typed text, give them Jsig too.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you know about actual "digital signatures".
I researched about those and their validity in law.
You should check out [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signatures_and_law) for laws based on the nation. Also look into this http: //www.uncitral.org/uncitral/en/index.html for general information and this http: //www.uncitral.org/pdf/english/texts/electcom/ml-elecsig-e.pdf for digital signature based law.
Sorry for not linking the URL properly, I need more reputation to do that. Just remove the space between the http: and //
Hope it helps.

Comment: Not a problem, thanks for the references to lead me in the right direction.